# Flexslider DirectionNav Doesn't Behave Like Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I hope I'm not violating any written or unwritten rules by asking for help on my business' site.

http://www.gnarlyweb.com/wrladv/

So I'm using Flexslider (but have tried at least 3 others) to handle showing multiple pieces of work on portfolio items. If you scroll to the Portfolio section, each item is clickable, and a flexslider appears. The Flexslider js is obviously working because the nav shows up, the images will animate if I have `slideshow: true`, but the arrows on the side do not make it move to the next piece.

I've been working on this for weeks now and can't figure it out. Does anyone know why only half of the Flexslider library works in this situation?

I know it's not Flexslider's fault, because I can put together a jsfiddle with the sources from the portfolio area and have it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I see all your images are in one flexslider container and they are dynamic.

I think this may cause this problem.

But i'm not pretty sure.

My suggestion is: different flexsliders for different images

Comment: The images are not dynamic - they're added when the page loads, but hidden by setting they're container to `display:none;` and then when someone clicks on the portfolio-item the `display` is changed to `block`. There's no Ajax going on, other than checking to see if the user is logged in to know where the stickynav bar goes.

Comment: Also, it's already doing multiple flexsliders; I've thought about doing a single `#flexslider` and swapping the `.slides` every time someone clicks a portfolio item.

Comment: I know there's no Ajax going on, I've seen your js code, i found that you binding the flexslider only once when page load and all images loaded. I didn't see any multiple flexsliders, only change images in the .slides . Maybe i'm wrong , but your page is 404 now.

Comment: I found a hack-ish solution and because it was extremely specific to me, I opted to take down the site and flag this question to be removed. In response to your comment, if the selector returns an array of matched elements, does it bind the same flexslider to all of them? `$(".portfolio-slides")` matches about 6 elements right now, so does `$.fn.flexslider` bind the same one to all six or create a new one for all six?

Comment: In other words, should `$(".portfolio-slides").each(function(){ $(this).flexslider(); })` have fixed my problem?

Comment: I have use **class** to bind a number of sliders, but didn't work. So i don't think `.each` can fixed your problem, my solution is bind them by **id**

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving anything for the flexslider script to reference in your html. Looks like your basic html setup for your flexslider is:

```
<div class="portfolio-slides">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

By default, the flexslider script searches for the flexslider class. You can either go into your flexslider script and add,

```
$(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.portfolio-slides').flexslider({
    });
});
```

or change your div class name to flexslider. The issue you're going to run into is that you have multiple flexsliders so you're going to have to create unique tags and have jquery call on each one otherwise all the flexsliders sync up.

Comment: www.gnarlyweb.com:8080/wrladv/wp-content/themes/wrladv/js/wrladv.js:249

Line 249 is where I'm calling flexslider. Why do you wrap `$(window).load` inside `$(document).ready` instead of just `jQuery(function($){ ... });`

Comment: I just copied the original code and replaced the class tag. I apologize for missing that js file. Good luck.